Filter the items inside of Gutenberg mediaUpload for a certain custom block
I want to use the core media picker inside of a block. For the block im working on I need to only return images that contain "xyz-".
I can get my desired results GLOBALLY with the hook "ajax_query_attachments_args"
I am using the mediaUpload component in my block.
function filter_media_library_for_icons($query) {
    $query['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_attached_file',
            'value' => 'xyz-',
//            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE', // exclude
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    );

    return $query;
}
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', 'filter_media_library_for_icons', 10, 1);

I am looking for a way to achieve similar functionality but ONLY within a custom block.
Any recommendations or places to look would be appricated!
I cant use allowedTypes
